# Disable video gravity change animation when using an AVPlayerViewController and AVQueuePlayer

Tags: avfoundation

In IOS 8.1, is it possible to disable the aspect ratio change animation when changing the video gravity of an  AVPlayerViewController instance?

If so, how?